# Python + FuncDesigner error correction

Tags: python

```
from FuncDesigner import *
a, b, c = oovars('a', 'b', 'c')
f = [2*a+3*b-2*c+5, 2*a+13*b+15, a+4*b+2*c-45]
linSys = sle(f)
r = linSys.solve()
A, B, C =  r(a, b, c)
maxRes = r.ff
```

when I execute this code in terminal it is showing the error

```
"TypeError: formDictOfFixedFuncs() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)"
```

I don't know what to do
Please help me

Comment: Please provide the full traceback. Also, the code you're showing seems unrelated with the error.

Comment: Where do you call `formDictOfFixedFuncs()`?

Answer (score 0):

works for me (I have latest svn snapshot v 0.51+)

> > > A, B, C 
> > >       (24.999999999999996, -4.9999999999999991, 19.999999999999996)
> > >       maxRes
> > >       7.1054273576010019e-15